# Adjusting the "G" Format specifier's method of displaying the exponential format (or replacing with custom numeric string)

Tags: c#, double, number-formatting

When I display a double as a string using the standard numeric format "G4", I get the following results:

```
.0000001 -> 1E-07
.000001 -> 1E-06
.00001 -> 1E-05
.0001 -> 0.0001
.001 -> 0.001
.01 -> 0.01
.1 -> 0.1
1 -> 1
10 -> 10
100 -> 100
1000 -> 1000
10000 -> 1E+04
100000 -> 1E+05
```

I would rather have the following (changed lines are starred):

```
.0000001 -> 1E-7 **
.000001 -> 1E-6 **
.00001 -> 1E-5 **
.0001 -> 0.0001
.001 -> 0.001
.01 -> 0.01
.1 -> 0.1
1 -> 1
10 -> 10
100 -> 100
1000 -> 1000
10000 -> 1E4 **
100000 -> 1E5 **
```

How can I accomplish this with a standard or custom numeric format string?  Is this even possible with just a numeric format string?

Comment: @GrantWinney: Yeah, I want the smaller values to NOT be scientific notation.

Comment: If someone who really knows that this isn't possible could say so, and show why, I could perhaps move on.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be nice if someone posted a string format that did exactly what you needed, but until then...

The following extension method will do what you want:

```
public static string ToFormattedString(this double i)
{
    var sciNumber = i.ToString("G4");

    // If the number has no exponent (such as .0001 or 100), return it as-is
    if (!sciNumber.Contains("E"))
        return sciNumber;

    var parts = sciNumber.Split('E');

    return string.Concat(parts[0], "E", Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]));
}
```

By getting the exponent portion of the string and converting it to a double again, we can (as a side-effect) end up converting `-07` to `-7` and `+04` to `4`.

Should be able to call it using:

```
var input1 = .0000001;
var input2 = 10000;

var output1 = input.ToFormattedString();  // 1E-7
var output2 = input.ToFormattedString();  // 1E4
```

Comment: +1, although `ToInt32` would probably be a better choice then `ToDouble` in the return value.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in my case I'm actually limited to using numeric format strings (working with a 3rd party dll).